# Apply JavaScript to only a part of the code (example a menu)

Tags: javascript

For my page I use 2 JavaScript (external .js), one for the navigation menu:

```
src="js-menu/bootstrap.min.js"
```

And for the whole html page:

```
type="text/javascript" src="js/front.min.js"
```

The problem is that the whole page **.js** has some old menu coding and this interferes with my menu JavaScript.

I am a JavaScript beginner so I don't know how to correct it there, I would like to make my `nav-menu` **.js** applying only to my navigation `div` instead ...

Any idea ?
thanks

Comment: the iframe is the only solution that i see. Isolate your menu in a iframe.

Comment: Actually *correcting* the code seems like a more viable solution than trying to find some hack to make the code somehow not apply to parts of the page.  Take this as a good opportunity to learn some JavaScript/DOM debugging.  Find out *why* the code is doing something you don't want it to do and modify it so that it doesn't do that.  It could be as simple as changing an element class somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try separating the code into different files. It can help in figuring out what is going on. Create a new file, called "temp_something", and copy all of the code into it. Then, try things like removing all of the other JavaScript files, but leave yours in. Then, comment out all code but the "bare minimum" code, and then slowly uncomment code. This may help you by giving you a starting point on where the problem may be.